# What is the smallest polynomial with almost linear condition?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation-theory

What is the smallest degree univariate polynomial with $f(0)=0$, $f(1)\in(0,0.5)$ and $f(x)={x-1}+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon\in(-0.5,0.5)$ at every $x\in\{2,\dots,a-1,a\}$?

Can we have $O((\log a)^c)$ degree.

Comment: @dxiv that is what I thought and so I have modified the query

Comment: Just a different phrasing, but with $\,g(x)=f(x)-x+1\,$ the question is equivalent to finding the "*smallest*" $\,g\,$ such that $\,g(0)=1\,$, $\,0 \lt g(1) \lt 0.5\,$, and $\,|g(x)| \lt 0.5\,$ for $x = 2,3,\dots,a\,$. Too bad you look for a polynomial, otherwise a dampened sine wave would work just fine.